# Capistrano error tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: capistrano, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3

```
 INFO [050fe961] Running mkdir -p /home/rails/rails-
capistrano/releases/20140114234157 on staging-rails
DEBUG [050fe961] Command: cd /home/rails/rails-capistrano/repo && ( PATH=/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/rails/git-ssh.sh mkdir -p /home/rails/rails-capistrano/releases/20140114234157 )
 INFO [050fe961] Finished in 0.142 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [2dea2fe5] Running git archive feature/Capistrano | tar -x -C /home/rails/rails-capistrano/releases/20140114234157 on staging-rails
DEBUG [2dea2fe5] Command: cd /home/rails/rails-capistrano/repo && ( PATH=/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/rails/git-ssh.sh git archive feature/Capistrano | tar -x -C /home/rails/rails-capistrano/releases/20140114234157 )
DEBUG [2dea2fe5]    fatal: Not a valid object name
DEBUG [2dea2fe5]    tar: This does not look like a tar archive
DEBUG [2dea2fe5]    tar: 
DEBUG [2dea2fe5]    Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I am confused about two things:

1. Why is Capistrano running `git archive` here:
   `git archive feature/Capistrano | tar -x -C /home/rails/rails-capistrano/releases/20140114234157`
2. Why is `tar` failing?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

I had the same issue, until I realized I was pulling the nonexistent branch from git.

Comment: Such a forehead smacker.

Comment: Second time i encounter your answer, second time this happened, i feel dumb!

Comment: Dumb, dumb, dumb. Though, I do have an excuse (here we go!) I was copy/pasting config from another project. (I know, shameful.)

Comment: I'm glad that this question has so many upvotes. At least I don't fail lonely.

Comment: This may be a reason for the problem but does not really answer the questions presented. Eric didn't seem to resolve his issue this way. I'll post an alt. answer.

Comment: if I am here, I am also the dump, thank you for solution btw

Comment: God Bless you, I could spend a whole day

Comment: Seriously, this is probably the 42nd time I'm doing the same google search and reading this answer xD

Comment: there should be check of the branch name

Comment: I spent 5 minutes thinking "This is not my problem"... Yes it was.

Comment: I have joined the cclub today!

Comment: Even now, four years later, this answer is still relevant. Many thanks!

Comment: You just saved my 5+ hours which i was estimating to put in resolving this.. God bless you the saviour

Comment: faced the same issue. I intended to deploy `main` branch and it was searching for `master` branch. Then I did `bundle exec cap production deploy BRANCH=main`
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9068104/5989038) for reference

Comment: It's so fun :)), I had a problem the same. Many thanks

Comment: Now that more people are using a `main` branch instead of `master`, I suspect more people will face this issue :)

Comment: You can set your branch on deploy.rb with: `set :branch, "main"`
PS Go upvote yosefbennywidyo answer

Answer (score 19):

Deleting app_name/repo also fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This has worked for me some times whenever there are repo issues with cap deploy but not always.

Answer (score 19):

This happens when the repo in the server to deploy is messed up. We're talking about the bare git repo that Capistrano by default would put in `/var/www/$application/repo` (for other people's reference).

In your case it does not have a local *feature/Capistrano* branch so when running `git archive feature/Capistrano` nothing is output to that `|` pipe. To confirm, ssh into the server, cd into /home/rails/rails-capistrano/repo, and run `git branch`.

1. It's running [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) as a way to export the selected branch's tree. **git archive** "writes it out to the standard output" so Capistrano redirects that to **tar** in order to uncompress the archive immediately into your new release directory.
   (Why Capistrano chose this instead of git checkout defeats me.)
2. **tar** fails because it's receiving nothing d:

I can think of two possible solutions/ways to troubleshoot:

- ssh into the server and manually delete the repo folder (e.g. in your case /home/rails/rails-capistrano/repo) as mentioned by @lugolabs
- make sure the server's repo is using the remote you're expecting (ssh in, cd into repo/, and run `git remote -v`) -- you may just need to update your `:repo_url` in deploy.rb (and delete the repo/ dir).

Comment: Do we have another way instead of deleting the current repo?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I have hit this error it was because the branch specified in my deploy/**environment**.rb  file wasn't checked into git.  Do an add / commit / git push origin **branch_name** and that will likely make things work.

Answer (score 4):

I think that folder gets populated via a git pull, so it shouldn't be empty. If you do see it empty the issue is from the git not the tarball.

The issue I had was my capistrano deploy.rb repository URL was set to a different one than that project i was working in. In order to fix this issue, I also had to logon to the server and delete the app_name/repo folder which must have been caching the original bad remote URL.

Comment: for googling folks: also check if you set existing branch !!! ...worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set your branch on `deploy.rb` with:
`set :branch, "main"`

[source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1065#issuecomment-55083453)

*Note: the default branch is `master`*

Comment: My default was 'main' also, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bedrock Roots (wordpress) for development, capistrano for deploys and git flow.
Stumbled upon this error when tried to deploy, while on hotfix/x.x.x branch locally. So I finished current (merged changes to develop branch) and then successfully deployed.

Comment: Do you understand why merging into develop fixed your issue?

Comment: Deploying other branches may work, but the question remains why is the particular one you're trying to deploy not working? I may have an answer.

Comment: @EricFrancis Actually, I do now) As the voted answer states, hotfix didn't exist on remote (where capistrano deploys from)