# Capistrano Deploy not fetching latest commit from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano3

When I run 'cap production deploy' is am not getting my latest master on the server.  Here are so lines from the deploy log:

```
DEBUG[208486a4] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/----/git-ssh.sh   /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:------.git )
DEBUG[208486a4]     3983b992ede90e5957dc9ddb953c4df488354d7d    HEAD
DEBUG[208486a4]     3983b992ede90e5957dc9ddb953c4df488354d7d    refs/heads/master
DEBUG[208486a4] Finished in 0.832 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Then later on in the log:

```
INFO[38bea0b3] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch master (at 18306db) deployed as release 20140626124746 by dean; " >> /home/deploy/royalty/revisions.log on 96.126.121.168
DEBUG[38bea0b3] Command: echo "Branch master (at 18306db) deployed as release              20140626124746 by dean; " >> /home/deploy/royalty/revisions.log
INFO[38bea0b3] Finished in 0.116 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

I have recently switched from using a repo at assembla to github.  The commit: 18306db was the last commit that I pushed up to assembla.  But all the new commits after that show up when I view the repo on github.

I changed the origin url with set-url and then pushed the up to github.

What am I missing here?? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Finally found a question that was related here: [Capistrano error tar: This does not look like a tar archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126518/capistrano-error-tar-this-does-not-look-like-a-tar-archive)

And followed the advice in the second answer which worked for me.

Logged into server and deleted the app_name/repo folder (rm -rf /app_name/repo )

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my deployment problems after the repository owner was changed on Github.