# How to add ignored files from develpoment branch to a deploy branch in git

Tags: node.js, git, gitignore

I have a particular issue that isn't quite covered by the scenarios I have found so far, [here](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487753/how-to-realise-a-deployment-branch-in-git) (amongst others).

I have a node.js project and have decided not to include the node_modules directory in my git repo ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository) are some arguments for and against). However, I am setting up a regular deployment to a testing server and for this I would like to deploy the complete application, with the dependencies loaded (maybe in future I will also include the node server too, but for now just the dependencies).

So I create a test-deploy branch, on which I ignore the vagrant folder, some static pages, etc. I include the node_modules by removing it from the .gitignore file and then push the branch to a remote repository where I have set up hooks to inform my test-server there is a new deploy and it should pull from the remote.

How do I now go about checking out my development branch again? I have tried to add the node_modules back to the .gitignore file but when I checkout my development branch git (rightly so) removes all my node modules as they are not seen as part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I was trying some ideas and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files) answer on how to ignore previously committed files. Following this, after replacing the node_module directory in the .gitignore file I then ran the command

`git rm -r --cached node_modules/*`

adding the `-r` flag to deal with recursive directory traversal. Now when I swap back to to the development branch my module files are still there (although I lost my Vagrant box!)

So to summarise, in order to include ignored files in a deploy branch and not lose them when you checkout your development branch again you should:

- Checkout your deploy branch.
- Remove node_modules/* from your .gitignore file
- Add your module files to staging and commit, push or whatever you need to do
- Add node_mudules/* to your .gitignore files again
- Run `git rm -r --cached node_modules/*` to remove the files from the repository again.
- Now you can checkout your development branch without losing your node modules from that branch.

Comment: That's quite ugly as workflows go.  Have you considered putting the modules into another repo (or even just a different branch in the development repo) and checking them out independently (git submodule leaves config files which might affect your production deployment) ?

Comment: I looked at submodules and subtrees during this project, but found that both had issues. Doesn't your idea break the desire to have a complete project in one 'package'? Although I am deploying from my remote repo at the moment, that might change soon.

Comment: What is a "package"?  I do this as a single REPO, with a few branches.  In your example there might be a single repo with a main DEV branch, a PROD branch, and a branch with just the modules.   There is no law that says the submodule has to be a different repo.  Just checkout a different branch in the sub-repo.